# Base class constructor automatic call

Tags: c++

I have troubles understanding the output of the following code when it comes to the first printed number.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class A{
public:
    int x;
    A(){
        x = 5;
    }
};
class B: public A{
public:
    static int x;
    B(){
        x++;
    }
    B(int i){
        x = x+i;
    }
    B(string s){
        x--;
    }
};

int B::x=10;

int main()
{
B b1;
B b2(2008);
B b3("Random string");
cout << b1.x << " : " << b2.x << " : " << b3.x << endl;
return 0;
}
```

output (the first "2018" is the one I'm having troubles with)

```
2018 : 2018 : 2018
```

Comment: Since `x` is `static`, every instance of `B` shares it.  What output did you expect?

Comment: And the whole subclass is a red herring. Why bother even including that?

Comment: Not really a question in here. If you don't understand it why not take it apart bit by bit and put it back together again to see how it works?

Comment: Hey Rosalyo, What did you expect `b1.x` to output? Why did you expect it to be different from `b2.x`?

Comment: `x=10;` `x++` `x = x+2008` `x--;`  Which part confuses you about the final value of `B::x`?

Comment: if you understand the 2nd and 3rd `2018` then you already do understand the 1st. Why do you think they are any different?

Comment: I expected ```B b1;``` to simply increment x, i'd say i was waiting for it to print 11 instead of 2018.

Comment: To add to the confusion, there is also `B::A::x`, which is by instance, (but **hidden**)...

Comment: The question here now seems to be "What is a `static` member variable?"

Comment: Do you mind  enlightening me ?

Comment: It's not that I don't understand a static variable, it's more like me not getting why b1 that (seemingly) call b(),outputs 2018 instead of incrementing the static x to 11.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing to note is that `A::x` is different from `B::x`. `B` does inherit `A::x`, but it introduces a new `B::x` which is `static`. Hence `x` in the scope of `B`refers to `B::x` (not to `A::x`). Ergo, you can remove the base class without changing the output:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class B {
public:
    static int x;
    B(){
        x++;
    }
    B(int i){
        x = x+i;
    }
    B(string s){
        x--;
    }
};

int B::x=10;

int main()
{
    B b1;
    B b2(2008);
    B b3("Random string");
    cout << b1.x << " : " << b2.x << " : " << b3.x << endl;
}
```

[same output:](https://godbolt.org/z/Yz19nE71e):

```
2018 : 2018 : 2018
```

Now, `B::x` starts out as `10` because thats what you initialize it to. Then `B b1;` increments it (in the default constructor), then `B b2(2008);` adds `2008` to `B::x`, it is `2019` now. Eventually `B b3("Random string");` decrements it to arrive at the value `2018`. Because `B::x` is static you see 3 times the same output.

---

The confusion seems to be caused by `B::x` being a static member and `A::x` being hidden by `B::x`. To reiterate the above: `static int x;` declares `x` to be a static member. There is only 1 for all instances. When one instance increments it  then any other instance will see the incremented value as well. `B::x` hides `A::x` because they have the same name. I suppose this is not intentional. If your intention was to let `B` inherit `x` from `B` and use that, then you should remvoe the delcaration and definition of `B::x`.

---

> It's not that I don't understand a static variable, it's more like me not getting why b1 that (seemingly) call b(),outputs 2018 instead of incrementing the static x to 11

The line `B b1;` does increment `A::x` from `10` to `11`. Though the constructor does not produce any output. The values are only printed after all constructors finished.

Comment: I feel so stupid, thanks guys.

Comment: and `b1.x` is actually `(static_cast<void>(b1), B::x)`.

Answer (score 1):

Your **static data member** `x` inside the derived class `B` **hides** the **nonstatic data member x** from base class `A` since they both have the same name. The explanation of the output is given below.

##### Case 1

Here we consider the statement:

```
B b1;
```

The above statement has the following effects:

1. It calls the default constructor `B()` of class `B`.
2. Then the default constructor `A()` of class A is **implicitly** called. This sets the **non-static** data member `x` of the subobject to `5`.
3. Finally, the body of the default constructor `B()` is executed. Due to this `x++;` is evaluated and so `x` now is `11`. This is because the non-static data member `x` from base class `A` is **hidden** by the static data member `x` of derived class `B`. So `x++;` increments the static data member(which was `10`) instead of the nonstatic data member from base `A`.

##### Case 2

Here we consider the statement:

```
B b2(2008);
```

The above statement has the following effect:

1. The parameterized ctor `B(int)` of class `B` is called.
2. Then the default ctor `A()` of class `A` is **implicitly** called. This sets the **non-static** data member `x` of the subobject to `5`.
3. Finally, the body of the parameterized ctor `B(int)` is executed. Due to this `x = x + i;` is evaluated and so the static data member `x` becomes `2019`(since x was `11` and `i` is `2010`). This is because the non-static data member `x` from base class `A` is **hidden** by the static data member `x` of derived class `B`. So `x = x+i;` uses the static data member(which was `11`) instead of the non-static data member from base `A`.

##### Case 3

Here we consider the statement:

```
B b3("Random string");
```

The above statement has following effects:

1. The parameterized ctor `B(std::string)` of class `B` is called.
2. Then the default ctor `A` of class `A` is **implicitly** called. This sets the **non-static** data member `x` of the subobject to `5`.
3. Finally, the body of the parameterized ctor `B(std::string)` is executed. Due to this `x--;` is evaluated and so now `x` contains `2018`. This is because the non-static data member `x` from base class `A` is **hidden** by the static data member `x` of derived class `B`. So `x--;` decrements the static data member(which was `2019`) instead of the non-static data member from base `A`.

So now the static data member `x` has the value `2018`.

##### Case 4

Here we consider the statement:

```
cout << b1.x << " : " << b2.x << " : " << b3.x << endl;
```

The above statement uses the static data member `x` values because the non-static data member `x` is hidden. And since the static data member `x` has the value `2018` you get the output you mentioned.